# How to implement roulette wheel for picking random objects in python?

Tags: python, random, probability

In python, I have a list of objects (size of list is >= 2), which have a property called `score` which has a value which is any float that's >= 0 (no upper bound).

I want to randomly pick 2 different objects from the list, but make sure that there is a higher chance of picking a value that has a higher score. Basically the higher the score the more chance of being picked. I was thinking of doing a roulette style, where I take a sum of all scores, and then getting a perfect of each item where it's percent is its score divided by the total score.

But how do I still pick the 2 objects?

Thanks

Comment: Once you choose the first object, is it replaced in the list, i.e., can it be chosen again the second time?

Answer (score 2):

The question is not super clear, but I think I get what you mean. 
You should use a inverse CDF type approach. The below example will return you an index for your list of scores, then just use that to get the value you want. Obviously there are smarter ways to do this from a programming point of view, but you clearly need to understand the method, which I think this example will help a lot with.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> scores = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
>>> scores = np.array(scores)
>>> sum = scores.sum()
>>> sum
1500
>>> percentages = scores/float(sum)
>>> percentages
array([ 0.06666667,  0.13333333,  0.2       ,  0.26666667,  0.33333333])
>>> cdf = percentages.cumsum()
>>> cdf
array([ 0.06666667,  0.2       ,  0.4       ,  0.66666667,  1.        ])
>>> cdf = np.concatenate([np.array([0]), cdf])
>>> cdf
array([ 0.        ,  0.06666667,  0.2       ,  0.4       ,  0.66666667,  1.        ])
>>>def returnobj(cdf, randnum):
>>>    for i in range(len(cdf)-1):
>>>        if((randnum>cdf[i])&(randnum<=cdf[i+1])):
>>>            return i
##########
#This Bit is just to show how the results look, and to show it favours higher scores
>>>for i in range(10000):
>>>    results.append(returnobj(cdf, np.random.random()))
>>>results=pd.DataFrame(results)
>>>results[results.columns[0]] = results[results.columns[0]].astype(str)
>>>results['a'] = results[0]
>>>print results.groupby(0).count()
0   639
1  1375
2  2039
3  2678
4  3269
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a static (class) variable to keep track of the maximum score that a single object has. Then I'd have a non-static method that evaluates the percentage of the instance's score compared to the maximum score. (Which is basically what you said)

In my main program I'd then use a normal `randrange` to pick the `index` of one of your objects. Then I'd call the percentage-function of that object and create another random variable between 0-1. If the variable is bigger than the outcome of the function pick the object, otherwise don't pick it. Repeat this until you've picked the desired amount of objects.

This is most likely not the best and flexible approach but it should give you the desired proportion.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that an item's score does not change, and that items are unique.

The best way to get a random weighted item is to index into a list of cumulative weights.

To get a sample, just keep picking random items until you have enough unique values.

The code:

```
from bisect import bisect_left
from itertools import accumulate
from random import random, shuffle

class WeightedRandom:
    def __init__(self, items, weights):
        self.items    = list(items)
        self.weights  = list(weights)
        self.cum_wt   = list(accumulate(weights))
        self.total_wt = self.cum_wt[-1]

    def random(self):
        value = random() * self.total_wt
        index = bisect_left(self.cum_wt, value)
        return self.items[index]

    def sample(self, n):
        items = set()
        while len(items) < n:
            items.add(self.random())
        # Note: casting from set to list introduces
        #   an ordering bias; we have to remove this bias.
        items = list(items)
        shuffle(items)
        return items
```

then

```
>>> roulette = WeightedRandom("ABCDEFGHIJ", range(1, 11))
>>> for i in range(10):
...     print(roulette.sample(2))
['J', 'D']
['J', 'C']
['I', 'F']
['C', 'H']
['J', 'E']
['A', 'G']
['J', 'H']
['E', 'I']
['I', 'D']
['E', 'I']
```

Note, though, that `sample` may take a long time to run if the first (n - 1) items sum to a large fraction of `total_wt`!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a "simple" code to do what I think you want.

The trick is to choose one, remove it from the list and try again.

This solution will work for any number of items you want to pick out...

```
import random

class Obj(object):

    def __init__(self, score):
        self.score = score


    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Obj %.2f>"%self.score


def get_items(l, num=2):
    if num==0: return []
    total = sum(o.score for o in l)
    for obj in l:
        obj._chance = obj.score / total
    l = sorted(l, key=lambda o: o._chance)
    selected = l[0] #float problems resolved ;)
    r = random.random()
    chance = 0.0
    for o in l:
        chance += o._chance
        if chance > r:
            selected = o
            break
    l.remove(selected)
    return [selected] + get_items(l, num-1)

l = [Obj(1.0),Obj(2.0),Obj(3.0)]

print (get_items(l, num=2))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is several ways of doing that using a library like tensorflow of numpy:

```
tf.random.categorical([tf.math.log(probs)], 1).numpy()[0][0]
```

or:

```
np.random.multinomial(1, probs/sum_probs).argmax()
```

but a simple function using the random module should do the trick:

```
def roulette_wheel(re: random.Random, probs: List[float], sum_probs: float):
    """Returns the index of chosen element, with probability proportionate to its value"""

    n = re.uniform(0, sum_probs)
    for i, p in enumerate(probs):
        if n <= p:
            return i
        n -= p
    raise ValueError(f"{sum_probs} should be equal to {sum(probs)}")
```